# Copying files from docker container to the host fails

Tags: docker, docker-cp, sitespeedio

I'm using sitespeed to test our website. But the reports were generated in the docker container, but not on the host.

So, I'm trying to use `docker cp` to get the reports. I can view the reports in the folder by executing the command:

```
docker exec wizardly_thompson ls /sitespeed.io/sitespeed-result/www.sitespeed.io/2020-03-31-11-26-52
```

But when I run the command:

```
docker cp wizardly_thompson:/sitespeed.io/sitespeed-result/www.sitespeed.io/2020-03-31-11-26-52/. d:/Engineer/SiteSpeed/
```

It tells me:

> No such contaniner：path:

Comment: Can you paste the output of this: `ls -la /sitespeed.io/sitespeed-result/www.sitespeed.io/2020-03-31-11-26-52/`

Comment: Below is the output  
>total 136  
>drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4096 Mar 31 11:27 .  
>drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 Apr  1 00:42 ..  
>-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12292 Mar 31 11:27 .DS_Store  
>-rw-r--r--  1 root root  9038 Mar 31 11:27 assets.html  
>drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 31 11:27 css  
>-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14906 Mar 31 11:27 detailed.html  
>-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2968 Mar 31 11:27 domains.html  
>drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 31 11:27 font  
>-rw-r--r--  1 root root 26974 Mar 31 11:27 help.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes, like this:

```
docker cp wizardly_thompson:'/sitespeed.io/sitespeed-result/www.sitespeed.io/2020-03-31-11-26-52/.' 'd:/Engineer/SiteSpeed/'
```

If that doesn't work, try double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Comment: Both ways don't work. BTW, thank you for edit the question. This is the first time for me to ask a question here.